# Prevent app from being installed on Honeycomb

Tags: android, installation, android-3.0-honeycomb

Is there a way to prevent an app from being installed on Android Honeycomb?
I am looking for either a market filter or a manifest option.

Comment: What are you trying to avoid? Is there some kind of compatibility problem?

Comment: I'd like to be able to provide Honeycomb specific version for the application in Market, without having to put all the new code in the "older" version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this discussion on google groups](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/d4e1171be52819e7) (android-developers list), setting maxSdkVersion="10" will block Honeycomb; however it won't stop a device upgrading to Honeycomb (or force app uninstall) once your app is installed.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. However, documentation in developer.android.com states: "Future versions of Android (beyond Android 2.0.1) will no longer check or enforce the android:maxSdkVersion attribute during installation or revalidation." At least it should help with Market.

Answer (score 1):

In your Android Manifest file, set the `uses-sdk` [tag](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html). Android 3.0 is [level 11](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/api-levels.html). Also note, however, that Google explicitly states that they make their code backwards compatible so you don't have to do this. If you have a good reason to, go ahead, but be aware that Google thinks most people should never have to.

Comment: I remember reading a google employee saying the maxSdkVersion is deprecated, as it didn't really make sense as the device OS could be updated after the app was installed. Unfortunately my google-fu is weak on tracking down a link.

Comment: Ah, I mis-remembered. The quote was "That is the reason we stopped supporting this attribute in the platform, it was dumb, and leads to really dumb behavior like that." The URL is http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/d4e1171be52819e7